# Cómo crear una función con un interval

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando crear una función en una librería en el que mediante un interval me diga cuando tiene datos. Pero no consigo que me devuelva true y eliminar el interval.

Pero me devuelve siempre false aunque entra en el if cuando hay datos.
Además de que no elimina todos los intervals que se crean.

Este es mi código:

```
public isLoadedData() {
    let loaded = false;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        const features = this.layer.getSource().getFeatures();
        if (features.length > 0) {
            loaded = true;
            clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
            loaded = false;
        }
    }, 1000);
    return loaded;
}
```

Comment: Es probable que necesites trabajar con [eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events). (O si trabajas en Node: [Events API](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html)). Saludos

Comment: para ello existe una funcion  llamada [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)`

Comment: ¿Por qué necesitas el interval? si quieres saber si **ahora** hay datos, entonces puedes simplemente comprobarlo llamando a `this.layer.getSource().getFeatures()` y comprobar el valor actual

Comment: No edites la pregunta agregando la solución, mejor responde la pregunta en el área de respuestas, explicando la solución hallada. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Creo una promesa y dentro un interval.

Así cuando features no es un array vacío, devuelve true y elimino todos los intervals que se han podido generar.

SOLUCIÓN:

```
public isLoadedData() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.intervals.push(interval);
            const features = this.layer.getSource().getFeatures();
            if (features.length > 0) {
                this.clearAllIntervals();
                resolve(true);
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
}

private clearAllIntervals = () => {
    this.intervals.forEach((interval: any) => {
        clearInterval(interval);
    })
}
```